# Assigning a slice of struct

Tags: go, struct, initialization, slice, variable-assignment

I am trying to represent a slice data as json format so that I can use this [vs-code-extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hediet.debug-visualizer).

But I am getting error in the last line of the for loop.

**Error: append(formatted.Rows, col_i) (value of type []RowStructure) is not usedcompilerUnusedExpr**

Please help me find out what am I doing wrong and what should be the correct way of assigning slice of structs.

Thankyou

```
type ColumnStructure struct{
    Content string
    Tag string
}
type RowStructure struct{
    Column ColumnStructure
}

type format struct{
    Kind map[string]bool
    Text string
    Rows []RowStructure
}

func serialize(s []int){
    var formatted format
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        var col_i = ColumnStructure{
            Content: string(s[i]),
            Tag: string(s[i]),
        }
        append(formatted.Rows,col_i)
    }
}

func main() {
    var s = []int{1, 12, 30, 4, 5}
    formatted_data := serialize(s)
    fmt.Println(formatted_data)
    }
```

Comment: The application discards the result of `append`.  This is almost alway an error.  It looks like you want `formatted.Rows = append(formatted.Rows,col_i)`.   Also, change `serialize` to return `formatted` as expected by `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing certain changes to the code, following code works fine now.
But I am still not able to get the visualizations from [this vs-code-extension.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hediet.debug-visualizer)

```
type ColumnStructure struct {
    Content string
    Tag     string
}
type RowStructure struct {
    Column ColumnStructure
}

type format struct {
    Kind map[string]bool
    Text string
    Rows []RowStructure
}

func serialize(s []int) format {
    var formatted format
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        var col_i = ColumnStructure{
            Content: string(s[i]),
            Tag:     string(s[i]),
        }
        var row = RowStructure{
            Column: col_i,
        }
        formatted.Rows = append(formatted.Rows, row)
    }
    return formatted
}

func main() {
    var s = []int{1, 12, 30, 4, 5}
    formatted_data := serialize(s)
    fmt.Println(formatted_data)
    for i := 0; i < len(s)-1; i++ {
        if s[i] < s[i+1] {
            s[i], s[i+1] = s[i+1], s[i]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get this visualization: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hediet/vscode-debug-visualizer/master/docs/demo.gif

Comment: Sounds like you should make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) specifically for the vs code extension and post a separate question about it :)